# HTML input text with custom pattern

Tags: html

I am creating a web form that has a field which should keep the following pattern:

xxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx

All characters must be numbers and, if possible, I want to show the field as this example:

[image]

This is my current proposal, but the output is not the desired.

```
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <label for="numero_ticket" class="h4">Número de Ticket para facturar (30 digitos)</label>
                <input type="numero_ticket" class="form-control" id="numero_ticket_facturar" pattern="[0-9\s]{4,4}[0-9\s]{3,3}[0-9\s]{6,6}[0-9\s]{4,4}[0-9\s]{4,4}[0-9\s]{3,3}[0-9\s]{5,5}" placeholder="Número de Ticket para facturar" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
```

How could I put the underscore character, that should help the user to know the exact number of needed numbers to enter in the form field?

Comment: Since there are gaps, going to require more than one input box.

Comment: 30 separate inputs

Comment: @epascarello, an example where I could see how to do it?

Comment: @j08691, an example where I could see how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're describing using some CSS tricks and JQuery

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  if($(this).val().length >= 4){
    $(this).next('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
}

#longInput{
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 32px;
}

input{
  border: none;
  width: 6ch;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
        dimgrey 0, 
        dimgrey 1ch, 
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 1.5ch) 
      0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  color: dimgrey;
  font: 5ch consolas, monospace;
  letter-spacing: .5ch;
}
input::after{
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
16 digit number:<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="longInput">
    <input maxlength="4"></input>
    <input maxlength="4"></input>
    <input maxlength="4"></input>
    <input maxlength="4"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine, now I need to send the input values to a remote database, are all the values stored as a unique value under the same id tag or do I need to store each input value separately?

Comment: You'd need to store them separately but concatenating them should be fairly simple. Give them each the same class or us the parentID and then loop through them with `.each()`. Could you mark the question answered as well?